# paginator in jQuery is not working with autocomplete for me

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i use Pagination with sorting using jquery. also i have autocomplete functionalities also enabled.

Below is for the autocomlete

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=resourcePath %>/css/autocomplete.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=resourcePath %>/scripts/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=resourcePath %>/scripts/script.aculo.us/effects.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=resourcePath %>/scripts/script.aculo.us/controls.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=resourcePath %>/scripts/autocomplete.js"></script>
```

and this for pagination and sorting

```
<script src="<%=resourcePath%>/data-page/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Table Sorter -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=resourcePath%>/data-page/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $.noConflict(true);
                $(function() {      
                        $("#product-table").tablesorter();

        }); 
    </script>
    <link href="<%=resourcePath%>/data-page/table-sorter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="<%=resourcePath%>/data-page/smartpaginator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var t = document.getElementById('total').value;
        //var r = document.getElementById('rec_per_page').value;
            $('#paginator').smartpaginator({ totalrecords: t, recordsperpage: 10, datacontainer: 'product-table', dataelement: 'tr', initval: 0, next: 'Next', prev: 'Prev', first: 'First', last: 'Last'});
        });
    </script>
```

when i remove the following pagination and sorting working and autocomplete is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=resourcePath %>/scripts/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
```

when i add the above than it is vice versa.

how to overcome this?

Please help me.

Regards

Comment: check the order of the javascripts which are used in your page

Answer (score 1):

Depending the order in which you load your scripts you should not always be using `$.noConflict();` to release control of `$` from jQuery. The best way of doing it would be to use `jQuery` instead of `$` wherever jquery code is implemented, like so:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Also you are calling `$.noConflict()` and are still using on the very next like the jQuery DOMReady function with `$`. This:

```
$.noConflict(true);
$(function() {      
    $("#product-table").tablesorter();
});
```

should be:

```
jQuery.noConflict(true);
jQuery(function() {      
    jQuery("#product-table").tablesorter();
});
```

**EDIT:**

Also to use the `$` inside the DOMReady event handler you need to pass it as a parameter. This:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

Should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

Comment: thanks for the post but still i am facing the same issue `ReferenceError: Prototype is not defined Source` is the exception i get,

Comment: Is is the prototype library file being loaded correctly? Check the Network tab of Developer Tools/Firebug and make sure it's being loaded.

Comment: the exception says "jQuery is not a function"
 :)

Comment: spider could you help on the issue

Comment: As @rajeshkakawat pointed out, have you checked if jQuery is loading correctly. Also do you have any other errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

not fully understood from the above answer. but it helped me to find what it is and why it occurs.

I got all the solution from [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)